# AndroidX androidx.core.content.FileProvider added into manifest give error on manifest ; Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-manifest, androidx

[image]

above code is my provider_paths.xml

then i add this into my manifest

```
    <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.packagename.package.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true"
            tools:replace="android:authorities">
        <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
    </provider>
```

then when i try to run the app its giving me error
**Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs**

then merge manifest show me this
[image]

can anyone help me with this issue? i am using android X currently.

Comment: You could follow the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error info suggesting you to do it this way,

```
<provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.packagename.package.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true"
            tools:replace="android:authorities">
        <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" 
                tools:replace="android:resource"
/>
    </provider>
```