# How to implement Copy of image and text to Clipboard in Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am developing an App in which I require a functionality of copy of text and also Image whichever the user wants and paste it in app .
so far I have accomplished the copy and paste of text data and also I have successfully copied the Image to clipboard but my application is not showing the copied image in keyboard like below also I don't know how to handle after the image shows in keyboard in my application and the user clicks on it in my app.

[image]

Comment: What research have you done? There's plenty of solutions to this on the internet and on this site.

Comment: well i have searched of copying image into clipboard found out that i had to regiter my application as a provider and then have to use ClipData.newUri and save the image URI given from content provider which is being copied to clipboard but i can not found that how to enable to show image in clipboard as shown in image in my question and what to do after that image is selected ......

Answer (score 0):

You must use `FileProvider` example : [how to use file provider in manifest](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65724575/12361096) (but dont forget to use `${applicationId}.provider` for `android:authorities`)

and use bellow code :

```
    public void CopyImageToClipboard(String dir, String fileName) {
        Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getContext(), getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", new File(dir, fileName));
        Object systemService = getContext().getSystemService("clipboard");
        ((ClipboardManager) systemService).setPrimaryClip(ClipData.newUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), null, uri));
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is an modified working version of code from[here](https://coderanch.com/t/333565/java/BufferedImage-System-Clipboard) to store store a BufferedImage into the system clipboard.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard;
import java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable;
import java.awt.datatransfer.UnsupportedFlavorException;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class ClipboardUtil {

    private static final Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();

    public static void copyToClipboard(BufferedImage img) {
        clipboard.setContents(new TransferableImage(img), null);
    }

    private record TransferableImage(Image i) implements Transferable {
    
        @Override
        public Object getTransferData(DataFlavor flavor)
            throws UnsupportedFlavorException {
            if (flavor.equals(DataFlavor.imageFlavor) && i != null) {
                return i;
            } else {
                throw new UnsupportedFlavorException(flavor);
            }
        }
    
        @Override
        public DataFlavor[] getTransferDataFlavors() {
            DataFlavor[] flavors = new DataFlavor[1];
            flavors[0] = DataFlavor.imageFlavor;
            return flavors;
        }
    
        @Override
        public boolean isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor flavor) {
            DataFlavor[] flavors = getTransferDataFlavors();
            for (DataFlavor dataFlavor : flavors) {
                if (flavor.equals(dataFlavor)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

To copy text to `clipboard`, use

```
copytext.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        ClipboardManager myClipboard;
        myClipboard = (ClipboardManager)getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
        ClipData myClip;
        String Text = "Hello World!";
        myClip = ClipData.newPlainText("text", Text);
        myClipboard.setPrimaryClip(myClip);

        Toast.makeText(this, "Copy", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
});
```

Comment: I am copying using this methodology by making application a provider 


 Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                    context,
                    BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",
                    new File(file_name)
            );
            ClipData clip =
                    ClipData.newUri(MainApp.Companion.getAppContext().getContentResolver(), "a Photo", uri);
            ServiceUtil.getClipboardManager(context).setPrimaryClip(clip);